# Typescript cannot detect parameter types on generic methods in index signatures

Tags: generics, interface, typescript

I have an interface defining an index signature:

```
interface MethodCollection {
    [methodName: string]: (id: number, text: string) => boolean | void;
}
```

Everything's good here, any method I add to such an object will have their parameter types recognized correctly:

```
var myMethods: MethodCollection = {
    methodA: (id, text) => {
        // id: number
        // text: string
    }
}
```

---

Now, I need to add a type parameter to these functions:

```
interface MethodCollection {
    [methodName: string]: <T>(id: number, text: string, options: T) => boolean | void;
}
```

The moment I do this, the TypeScript compiler barfs up:

> Parameter 'text' implicitly has 'any' type
>
> Parameter 'options' implicitly has 'any' type
>
> Parameter 'id' implicitly has 'any' type

And indeed, neither can IntelliSense trace the correct types any longer, they all become implicit `any`:

```
var myMethods: MethodCollection = {
    methodA: (id, text, options) => {
        // id: any
        // text: any
        // options: any
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I use generic methods with an index signature? I'm using Visual Studio 2013, my project is set to use TypeScript version 1.6.

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 1.8.6 in VS 2015 and that code works fine for me. Intellisense doesn't get broken or anything. The released version 1.8.5 of TypeScript for VS 2013 a few days ago. there are quite a few changes. Can you upgrade and see if it works?

Comment: @rgvassar The issue also seems to exist in 1.8.5. At least, when I type `tsc -v` into the Package Manager Console or into cmd, they both give 1.8.5.

Comment: I'd post a bug on their github. Maybe they can fix it with their next release.

Comment: @rgvassar Well according to you, it's already fixed in 1.8.6, no? (: If you are certain the issue is fixed in 1.8.6, I'll try to jam that version into VS2013.

Comment: I don't know why they call it 1.8.6 on Visual Studio 2015, but in the release notes, it says it's the same release.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work again now either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the type inference work by making the interface generic, and specify it when creating the variable.

```js
interface MethodCollection<T> {
    [methodName: string]: (id: number, text: string, options: T) => boolean | void;
}

var myMethods: MethodCollection<string> = {
    methodA: function(id, text, options) {
        // id :number,
        // text: string,
        // options: string
    }
}
```

With VSCode and tsc 1.9.0 (current typescript@next), it's the only way it works.

That wouldn't allow you to have different types for different methods though.

You can however give an optional type to the MethodCollection.

```js
var myMethods: MethodCollection<string | boolean> = {
    methodA: function(id, text, options) { 
        // options is string | boolean
    }
}
```

Comment: _"That wouldn't allow you to have different types for different methods though."_ - Unfortunately, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: @JohnWhite I figured, there is a workaround, by giving an optional type to T. I doubt type inference will work for each method separately though.

Comment: This has been [confirmed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7391#issuecomment-192375450) as an intentional limitation.